# Spring Rest Controller with HttpServletRequest for upload resulting in no input file upload in Swagger

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, spring-restcontroller

I have spring rest controller with some parameters and HttpServletRequest in input. I use it to stream input file. Simplifying:

```
@PostMapping(path = "...", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@Operation(summary = "Create document", description = "upload file for creating a document")
    @ApiResponse(content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, schema = @Schema(implementation = MyDTO.class)))
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Data found"),
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Request not compliant with the defined schema")
...
public ResponseEntity<MyDTO> myUpl(
        @PathVariable("myParam1") Long param1,
        @RequestParam(name = "myParam2", required = true) Integer myParam2,
        HttpServletRequest request ) {
```

So when I invoke swagger-ui and produce swagger yaml there is no file input.

The code works perfectly.

I need to clarify in swagger the input file for frontend team.

How can I do that?

EDIT:

Following other posts, temporanely added to controller:

```
@RequestBody(description = "Input file",
    content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, 
        schema = @Schema(implementation = MultipartRequest.class),
        encoding = @Encoding(name = "file", contentType = "application/pdf")))
```

At least I have in swagger yaml:

```
      requestBody:
    description: Input file
    content:
      multipart/form-data:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/MultipartRequest'
        encoding:
          file:
            contentType: application/pdf
```

and un swagger-ui:

```
Request body     multipart/form-data
  Input file
fileMap
  object
fileNames
  object
multiFileMap
  object
```

It's the right way? There's something better? Is it possible to show Input File button in swagger-ui?

Comment: Hello, I am facing also the same issue. Did you find any solution for that ?

Comment: Hi @kaissun, no, at this moment I agree with frontend team that what I noted down after EDIT in question is enough for them. No better solution, no input file button in swagger-ui...